# xcode is slow every time i edit code

Tags: performance, xcode

after updating to xcode 10.2 , it became so slow every time i edit any thing even a string, even i if do mistake it doesn't show me the error until it finish building, and when i fix the error or even if i delete the error line it will still show me the error on that line.
i always had problem with big projects specially when i edit storyboard but now its slow even when i edit code.
anybody had the same experience or knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Close XCode.
Navigate to your project file, right click and select "Show Package Contents", then delete the *.xcworkspace file.
Re-open Xcode.
Immediate fix for me.

Then don't use Code-folding ...